# First text and then upload images from Fb api

Tags: iphone, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

Recently i am making an app on facebook. So i have use facebook api. From api we got data from json parsing. Now in my app i am showing all update of user and his friends in table view. But problem is that when i get data from json parsing then application take so much time due to loading image in app. So i want that i show first text message and when view did load then upload images so that time will reduce. How do that  i have no idea? So tell how i fix it?

I have use synchronous method to parse data from json. What approach i will use so i can consume less time?

Comment: Take one array of all links of images and try lazy loading in tableview. and when json are parsing data you can use activity indicator.
Most of Time always taken when you allocate UIImage from NSData from contentofURL.So use lazy loading for array of image urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sort my problem by seeing sample provided by Apple docs named as lazy table. In that i have edit like as in lazy table image upload on scroll to table so i remove that function. Now in my table when table load then image also load at that instant.[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)